# How can I determine File System from Windows?

Tags: windows-10, filesystems

When I enter a USB drive on Windows I if it doesn't have a partition that is recognised by Windows and tools such as Disk Management say "No Media" or File System Unknown.

On Linux I can use tools like `fdisk` to confirm what kind of file system is present. What options are there to do this on Windows?

[image]

Comment: Disk Management and `diskpart` should be able to at least show you the size of the partitions on said device.

Comment: This link might help you further: http://superuser.com/questions/72361/tool-to-determine-filesystem-on-removable-media

Comment: `fdisk` does not tell you what filesystem is actually used. It just reads a (very generic!) code that indicates the *partition type*. That being said, your USB drive is most likely toast.

Comment: The drive has probably failed - please see https://superuser.com/questions/871850/usb-flash-drive-not-working-or-is-appearing-as-an-empty-disk-drive-disk-managem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows has very limited support for file systems.

ext2/3/4 and other Linux file systems are not supported. Only NT based file systems such as FAT, Fat16/32, exFAT, and NTFS.

`diskpart` and Disk Management can show volume information such as size but nothing else. Third-party programs can be much more helpful.

Web Links:

[Tool to determine filesystem on removable media](https://superuser.com/questions/72361/tool-to-determine-filesystem-on-removable-media)

Comment: Thanks the `testdisk_win.exe` command tool came in very handy.

Comment: Actually seeing a file listing proved even more useful than knowing what type of file system it is.

Comment: @ChrisGuest Where did you find `test_disk.exe`?

Comment: There was a link to this download page in one of the answers to "Tool to determine filesystem on removable media"
https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download